# Solspace Calendar : Only retrieve calendars that have events

Tags: solspace-calendar

I have a drop down that lists all the Calendars. However I would like to only show Calendars that have an event assigned to them.

I need something like the show_empty tag for EE Category Archive: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/category_archive.html#show-empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{exp:calendar:calendars}` to list calendars, and pass the `{calendar_id}` to `{exp:calendar:events}` or `{exp:calendar:cal}` to see if there are any event entries for that calendar.

Given that there can be variables clashes with common variables such as {total_results}, {count}, etc, you will likely need to embed the `{exp:calendar:events}` or `{exp:calendar:cal}` code.

Here's an example. In your template use:

```
<select name="something">
{exp:calendar:calendars}
  {embed="calendars/embed" calendar_id="{calendar_id}"}
{/exp:calendar:calendars}
</select>
```

Then, in `/calendars/embed`, use:

```
{exp:calendar:events calendar_id="{embed:calendar_id}" date_range_start="12 months ago" date_range_end="+12 months"}
    {if no_results}
    {/if}

    {if count == 1}
        [{calendar_id}] {calendar_title}<br />
    {/if}

{/exp:calendar:events}
```

Using a timeframe, with `date_range_start=""` and `date_range_end=""`, large enough to cover your events is important, or else you only get a subset of the total events present for a calendar.